# Upload a file to a file hosting site through java

Tags: java, file-upload, http-post, httprequest

I need to upload a file to the file hosting site(like mega file upload http://www.megafileupload.com/ ) through java, is it possible to upload the file from my local drive to the hosting site through some java methods.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if the hosting site provides public [APIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) to upload a file or if it allows uploading files via ftp or any other Protocol. So the answer to your question is "it depends on the hosting website".